# Creating a table in Android

Tags: android, coding-style, create-table

First post for me. I'm dabbling in Android development for the first time and have only limited Java programming experience. On to my question...

When creating multiple tables in a dbHelper class, which method is preferred?

Initializing variables to hold the creation strings...

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
            "create table notes (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "+
            "title text not null, body text not null);";

db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
```

or just...

```
db.execSQL("create table notes (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "+
            "title text not null, body text not null);"
);
```

I've seen it done both ways and I'm trying to understand why more code would be better than less.

Thanks!

Comment: best approach would be to store all your `final/constants` in a separate class. So that in `future` If any thing need to be change then you can easily change in one class.

Answer (score 0):

@MrCleanX Do like this.

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

// All Static variables
// Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "contactsManager";

// Contacts table name
private static final String TABLE_CONTACTS = "contacts";

// Contacts Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
private static final String KEY_PH_NO = "phone_number";

public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

// Creating Tables
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_PH_NO + " TEXT" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
}

// Upgrading database
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACTS);

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a best practice, you should create using constants. This will help you when you want to make some change to the table later

Answer (score 0):

Personally i prefer to keep them in final static String variables so that i can easily edit them in one place and that way would be easier for me to read it and change something that will apply maybe to more than one database. I think this is most preffered way by the most developers.

```
public class myVariables {
     public final static String firstTable = "firstTableCreationQuery";
     public final static String secondTable = "secondTableCreationQuery";
}
```

And you can access them very easily

```
...
db.execSQL(myVariables.firstTable);
db.execSQL(myVariables.secondTable);
...
```

Comment: I like this idea. Still seems like a bit more code than is necessary though. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah but think that you can always find workarounds to reduce your code's size!